# enabling of both authentication method LDAP and External User in owncloud

Tags: authentication, owncloud

Can we enable  both authentication method LDAP and External User in owncloud ?
we have two types of user internal and external.
for internal users we want to configure LDAP and
for external user we want to configure External User IMAP.

Please reply can we do this.